# Strange output from rails each do

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails each do method is acting strangely and I do not know why.

**controller**

```
def index
  @fabric_guides = FabricGuide.with_attached_image.all.order(:name)
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="guide-items">
  <%= @fabric_guides.each do |fabric| %>
    <div class="guide-container">
      <%= link_to fabric_guide_path(slug: fabric.slug) do %>
        <%= image_tag fabric.image if fabric.image.attached? %>
      <% end %>

      <div class="guide-info">
        <p class="g-name">
          <%= link_to fabric.name,
          fabric_guide_path(slug: fabric.slug) %>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I have two FabricGuide records so I expect two "guide-container" but I get three. Or more precisely I get two guide containers and a third block of text containing all the content from the last FabricGuide record.

[image: The dom]

I have almost an identical setup for articles and have never encountered this problem. I'd happily share more information if needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove `=` equal sign from your each loop of view code
like below :-

```
<% @fabric_guides.each do |fabric| %>
 ...
 ...
<% end %>
```

you have used this `<%= @fabric_guides.each do |fabric| %>` in your view that's why it shows all record in DOM.

The expression for erb tags is `<%  %>`
now if we want to print that tag too then we apply `<%=  %>`